# ES2015 parallax scroller program structure?

Tags: javascript, animation, structure

I'm trying to build a simple and customizable ES2015 parallax scroller.

My question is about structuring code containing low-level HTML5 instructions  such as requestAnimationFrame or setInterval(game_loop_method, 1000 / 60)

Nice to have:

a low size footprint in HTML code, thus to facilitate integration in the header of a webpage (saying a blog or a CMS) and non-intrusive jquerty inside the lib :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('parascroll/theme.json', function(theme) {
      var canvas = $('#ps').get(0);
      var ps = new ParaScroll({
        canvas: canvas,
        theme: theme,
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh'
      });
      ps.run();
    });
  });
</script>
```

and a flexible customizable config file based :

```
{
  "main": {
  "width": "100vw",
  "height": "100vh",
  "background": "#cfe"
},

"layers": [
  {
    "name": "floor-background",
    "sprites": 21,
    "velocity": "10",
    "top": "45%",
    "left": "0%",
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "25%",
    "background": "#afd",
    "spritesheet": "parascroll/spritesheet.png",
    "distro": [10, 20, 30, 10, 40] // statiscal distribution of sprites
  },

 // ... and so forth, for all layers
```

How to achieve such a result ?

(I'm not considering using some lib as PIXI, my feeling is that code is as-hoc enough not to using 10% of the lib...)

Regards

Comment: So? Are you expecting us to write your code? Show us what you have tried!

Comment: of course no... my tries are located now in the repo : https://github.com/hefeust/parascroll ! factorization made have been hard, and it s still remain offsets of layers problems, I l l repost in this direction sooner.